# Принятие POST запроса на клиенте

Tags: xml, post, api, get

Всем привет, интересует принятие POST запроса на любой машине в сети, можно ли вообще это как-то реализовать... Или может быть есть какие-то другие способы. 
Суть задачи - Есть сервис, у него есть api, в нем есть функционал для создание задачи внутри оболочки этого сервиса. Мне нужно автоматизировать процесс для отслеживания создание новой задачи. После чего выполняются некоторые действия на локальной машине. 
Вот собственно ссылка на [docs](https://planfix.ru/docs/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC:_API)

Answer (score 0):

Через любой высокоуровневый язык программирования.

1. Отправляешь запрос.
2. Принимаешь данные.
3. Парсишь XML.
4. Обрабатываешь данные.
5. Оборачиваешь это в цикл.

Этот вопрос решается множеством способов, тебе выбирать каким.